# Remove extra link text after pageload in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My application has Header & Footer are coming from different web content team site. I am including them in my MVC4 application.

And Header we have `logout` link which is dynamically creating and `TRAGET_GRL` based on where user in page (url). It is loading delay link.

```
<ul id="rml_header_top_links">
    <li class="cl_action_tag_wrapper">
       <a href="https://qa.company.com/secured/login?
                   TARGET_URL=
                    http://qa.company.com/application/work/employ">Logout</a>
       </li>
</ul>
```

Now I have to change this `href` and remove text anything after `work/employ`. 
How to do that?

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward. What problem are you having? Use `.attr("href")` to get and set the href.

Comment: The problem is href was generating after my page load.

Comment: Then you have to run your code after that. Without seeing how it's being generated, there's no way for us to give an answer.

Comment: @Barmar: Tell me how can remove text anything after `iapp/volpts/` once user click on link and send them that url?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
 var link = $('.cl_action_tag_wrapper > a');
 var href = link.attr('href');
 var index = href.indexOf('work/employ/');
 href=href.substring(0,index>0? index+12:index); //+12 because work/employ/ is 12 chars
 link.attr('href',href);
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hWEnN/2/)

Comment: I want remove text after `iapp/volpts/`

Comment: Is there anyway we can do this after user click on the link and redirect him to changed url?